# Local storage array is always over written when saving in Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, local-storage

I am using Angular, I am trying to save to local storage, the below code does this fine. But when I refresh the page and try to add more items (objects) to the local storage array, it overwrites it when actually it should add more items (objects) instead of over writing? Where could I be going wrong?

The array `public playlist = [];` is being shared across components via a service and that is the array that the objects are getting pushed to.

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PlaylistService } from '../../../services/playlist.service';
import { faSave } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-playlist-view',
  templateUrl: './playlist-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./playlist-view.component.scss']
})
export class PlaylistViewComponent implements OnInit {

  faSave = faSave;

  constructor(private list: PlaylistService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
        this.list.getPlaylist();

  }
}
```

**Playlist.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PlaylistService {

  public playlist = [];

  savePlaylist() {
    this.playlist = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('playlist'));
    localStorage.setItem('playlist', JSON.stringify(this.playlist));
    console.log('Saved', this.playlist);
  }

  getPlaylist() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('playlist') == null) {
      this.playlist = [];
    } else {
      this.playlist = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('playlist'));

    }
  }

  constructor() { 
  }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest putting the saving and retrieving of the playlist to and from `localStorage` in the service code. Also, always get from `localStorage` and merge with your local copy, then save the result. Right now, if two components save, whichever saves last will "win".

Comment: ok, thats sounds ok. How would I call those functions in each component? I understand I am taking the `save()` and `get()` functions and placing them in the service. But how would those functions be called in the components?

Comment: Like any other function; `this.list.get();`, `this.list.save();`....

Comment: So I have moved the save and get into the service and `ngOnit` I am calling the `this.list.getPlaylist();` But its the same result

Comment: Please read the remainder of my first comment.

Comment: please share your PlaylistService code and we can give you a code example in an answer.

Comment: I have added the playlist service code now. @JoshStevens

Comment: why is all your code not going through the service? why have you repeated logic? surely just calling your service calls in the component makes more sense.. have you tried doing that? literally calling this.list.savePlaylist() and this.list.getPlaylist() ... also i would highly suggest using a proper state management tool like redux if you are trying to save state. Saving that in a singleton service is not the best way to go here.

Comment: I added the service in the question, but all the proper code is above as should be. UPDATED.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing overriding behavior, which is correct as per your given code. As while saving in `localstore` you are getting what is already stored in `localstore` then assigning it to `playlist` and again saving the `playlist` stored in `localstore`.

You need to save the `playlist` first in `localstore` and then by getting it assign to class level `playlist`.

`savePlyaList` function should be as follows,

**Playlist.service.ts**

```
savePlaylist() {
    // first save the data 
    localStorage.setItem('playlist', JSON.stringify(this.playlist));
    // get what is saved afterwords
    this.playlist = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('playlist'));
    console.log('Saved', this.playlist);
}
```

Comment: That gives the same result?

Comment: can you provide stackblitz, so its bit easier to find out whats the problem here.

Comment: Ok one second I can set that up quickly

Comment: It seems to be working but when I refresh my app, and enter a new search query and press save it does the same thing by overwriting. However if I don't refresh and search for items it keeps the saved items. That might be a different question.